# Can I install Cynogen OS on my Yu Yuphoria 5010A?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, custom-roms, stock-android, micromax-yu-yuphoria

Basically I have multi touch issue on YU yuphoria,I recently googled and found that custom ROM can remove this problem,cyanogen in my case but all the tutorial were for 5010.So I need to know whether I can flash cyanogen or not?

Comment: Don't YU phones come with Cyanogen OS already? Are you talking about CyanogenMod instead?

Comment: Latest Yu Yuphoria Comes with pure Android Lolipop 5.1.1

Comment: The old model(5010) used to come with Cyanogen 12.

Comment: Here's the tutorial from official forum: http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/guide-flash-cos12-on-yuphoria-android-version.25868/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. (NOTE: these builds are for the build 'lettuce')

https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=lettuce